# Java webstart: unable to disable security dialog

Tags: java, java-7, java-web-start

We have a small Java Webstart application that we distribute to our customers. In the past, we used a self-signed certificate to sign the jar files, but with the changes recently introduced in Java 7u21, running the application was generating an annoying warning dialog that couldn't be suppressed, so we chose to purchase a proper code signing cert from Comodo.

Since then, a security information dialog appears every time we run our application (this is the blue shield dialog that indicates everything is ok, and is just there to show the user that the application is signed: first one here http://www.java.com/en/download/help/appsecuritydialogs.xml). This is expected behavior, on first launch.

The problem is that checking the box that says "Do not show this again.." does nothing. Every time the application is run, the dialog appears again.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: Try searching the [bug DB](http://bugs.sun.com/) & if you find nothing similar, raise a new report.  See what Oracle has to say on the matter.